# Validation at start of application and Refresh listview when validation executes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, listview, mvvm

I am developing a very simple application (I am learning C# WPF MVVM :)). I encountered 2 problems with validation.

Valdiation:
When Textbox is empty validation should start.

First problem is that, validation does not work at start of apllication. I have to write something in Textbox and then delete it. And then validation works. I want to start validation immediately after application runs.

[image]
View of my application at start (red border should be surrounded empty textboxes).

Second problem is that, my list with employees does not back to original form when valdiation executes.

[image]
Listview does not come back to original form.

Could you help me? Below I have placed code of my validators, xaml, models. If you need entire code let me know:)

Employee. cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace OneWayTwoWayBinding
{
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string employeeName;
        private int? employeeID;
        private int? employeeSalary;
        private string employeeDesigner;
        private string employeeEmailID;
        private Employee selectedEmployee;
        private ICollectionView filteredCollection;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
        private int? dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
        private int? dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
        private int isSelected;
        private string modeOfExecuting;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeName;
        private int? rememberValueEmployeeID;
        private int? rememberValueEmployeeSalary;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
        private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;


        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName));
                return employeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName));
            }
        }
        public int? EmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeID == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == employeeID);
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {

                employeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeID");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeID == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == employeeID);
            }
        }
        public int? EmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeSalary == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary == employeeSalary);
                return employeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeSalary");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeSalary == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary == employeeSalary);
            }
        }
        public string EmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(employeeDesigner)));
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeDesigner.Contains(employeeDesigner));
                return employeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDesigner");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeDesigner.Contains(employeeDesigner));
            }
        }
        public string EmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeEmailID.Contains(employeeEmailID));
                return employeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeEmailID");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeEmailID.Contains(employeeEmailID));
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return employees;
            }
            set
            {
                employees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
            }
        }

        public Employee SelectedEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                if (selectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    ModeOfExecuting = "Searching / Adding Mode";
                }
                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(selectedEmployee.SelectedEmployee.ToString())));
                    return selectedEmployee;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedEmployee = value;

                if (selectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    ModeOfExecuting = "Searching / Adding Mode";
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
                }

                if (selectedEmployee != null)
                {
                    if(selectedEmployee.EmployeeName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeName = selectedEmployee.EmployeeName;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeName = RememberValueEmployeeName;

                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeID != null)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeID = selectedEmployee.EmployeeID;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeID = RememberValueEmployeeID;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary != null)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeSalary = selectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = RememberValueEmployeeSalary;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeDesigner = selectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = RememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeEmailID = selectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = RememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
                    }

                    ModeOfExecuting = "Editing Mode";

                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeSalary");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeEmailID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID");
                }

                selectedEmployee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            }
        }

        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("null")));
                    EmployeeName = dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
                    //RememberValue = dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
                }

                return dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeName");
            }
        }
        public int? DynamicSearchEmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeID = dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeID");
            }
        }
        public int? DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeSalary = dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
                }

                return dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary");
            }
        }
        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeDesigner = dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner");
            }
        }
        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeEmailID = dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID");
            }

        }
        public ICollectionView FilteredCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return filteredCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                filteredCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCollection");
            }
        }

        public int IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                //SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName
            }
        }

        public string ModeOfExecuting
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(modeOfExecuting.ToString())));
                return modeOfExecuting;
            }
            set
            {
                modeOfExecuting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeName");
            }
        }
        public int? RememberValueEmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeID");
            }
        }
        public int? RememberValueEmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeSalary");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeEmailID");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;
        virtual protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Validators.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace OneWayTwoWayBinding
{
    public class OnlyIntOrNullRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            int result = 0;
            bool canConvert = int.TryParse(value as string, out result);
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                canConvert = true;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(canConvert, "Not a number");
        }
    }
    public class RequiredValuesToAddRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            bool RequiredValue = false;
            if ((string)value == string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("EMPTY");
                RequiredValue = false;
                //MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
            }
            else if ((string)value != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("NOTEMPTY");
                RequiredValue = true;
                //MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
            }
            return new ValidationResult(RequiredValue, "Value cannot be null");
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="OneWayTwoWayBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OneWayTwoWayBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ConverterStringFiltering x:Key="ConverterStringFiltering" />
        <local:ConverterButton x:Key="ConverterButton" />
        <local:ConverterIntFiltering x:Key="ConverterIntFiltering" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="EmployeeListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="0,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="{Binding IsSelected}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeName" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeID" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeSalary" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeSalary}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeDesigner" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeDesigner}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeEmailID" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeEmailID}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Label Content="Employee Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                    <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:RequiredValuesToAddRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                    </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeName"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmplyeeID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,91,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterIntFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:RequiredValuesToAddRule/>
                    </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeID"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>


        <Label Content="EmpoyeeSalary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name="TextboxEmployeeSalary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterIntFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:OnlyIntOrNullRule/>
                    </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmployeeDesigner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmployeeEmailID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox Name="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >

            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ModeOfExecuting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Height="37" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the validation not working right away, I found a similar question:

[WPF Validation not firing when first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868975/wpf-validation-not-firing-when-first-load)

If its solution doesn't work, I suggest raising some kind of property changed event on all of your text binded properties, as follows:

```
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName");
```

somewhere at the beginning of the program, constructor or such, after "InitializeComponents();" part.

Regarding your second problem;

I found a nice tutorial about the case:

[How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](https://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html#filtering)

In short, in order to clear the filter, you have to use ".Refresh", as follows:

```
FilteredCollection.Refresh();
```

You can put it wherever you'd like, my suggestion:

```
public string EmployeeName
{
    get
    {
        if (FilteredCollection != null)
            FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName));
        return employeeName;
    }
    set
    {
        employeeName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
        if (FilteredCollection != null)
            FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName));


        // The changes
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            ClearFilter();
    }
}

// The changes
private void ClearFilter()
{
    FilteredCollection.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: My list consists of 3 elements. When I write something in one of textboxes list is filtered and my list presents for example one mateched record.  When i delete a value from textbox my list should represents 3 elements.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand what you mean. It's GridView, not ListView even though it's inside one. At least that's how I see it, so it confused me. I'll think of a solution in a bit

Comment: I will check it. Your help for 1st question did not help :(

Comment: I recreated your whole program, I had to omit many irrelevant things, and I'm not sure what your ViewModel is, and how you connected the bindings and DataContext of stuff. Either way, my version, after I copy-pasted-deleted stuff is definitely flawed. I too can't fix your first concern, with validation on startup, but my problem is simply bad binding between "Target" (EmployeeName) and Validation class. I'm pretty sure that "ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"" AND together with it, updating the target, the "SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName" both together, ought to resolve the issue.

Comment: You might need to play with them for a bit. Either way, I'm saying it from my point of view, in which your binding are alright and it's not an issue. But, honestly it could be that the problem is entirely different, and the solution is in fixing datacontext, bindings and all the other things, which do not relate to this thing spicifically. Anyway, I wish you good luck. Do tell me if you get it fixed, I'm curious too

Comment: I also found another SO post with the same solution, you may want to look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644288/wpf-validationrule-validate-when-the-control-is-loaded

Comment: Hi:) I solved my problem by using IDataErrorInfo :). Later I will attach link to github with my source code :)